# c# specified cast is not valid while assigning mshtml.HTMLDocument.frames

Tags: c#, bho, mshtml, shdocvw

I'm developing an IE BHO, While accessing frames in a html document i'm getting this error

Here is the code.

```
foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer objExplorer in objShellWins)
{
   if (objExplorer.Document is HTMLDocument)
   {
      objDocument = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)objExplorer.Document;
      mshtml.HTMLDocument doc = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)objExplorer.Document;
      mshtml.FramesCollection frames = (mshtml.FramesCollection)doc.frames;  //Exception at this line
   }
}
```

what is the issue here ?

Comment: What is the error message from the exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK people i got it solved by setting `[STAThread]` at function calling

Comment: May be it conflicts with Windows.forms webbrowser control and mshtml webbrowser, also check the access permission for frames. What exception you get ?

Comment: The same which you are getting - specified cast is not valid exception. How to check access permission for frames?